# Asp mvc not showing errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that looks something like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               ...
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Msg = "error";
                return View();
            }
```

I've added the `ViewBag.Msg` to log the behavior of the controller. If the form isn't valid it should show the proper error messages acording to the model validators, but it's not working because the "error" string is being displayed on the view.

How can i track the error. Acording to the documentation `ModelState` has a property `Errors` but visual studio is saying that this is not true.

Is there another way log the error and what could it be.

**Edit:**

I already have the `@Html.ValidatorSumary(true)`, thats the wierd thing about this case, i know that `ModelState` is not valid because of the `ViewBag.Msg` line, but it's not showing a thing.

**Edit2**

It happens that I had a wrong value for one of the helpers like this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.BoolField, 1)
```

and the model

```
public Nullable<Bool> boolField { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try putting this in your view to see the errors: `Html.ValidationSummary(true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the Model back to the view to show the Model erros in the View. If you want to log the Model Errors, you can check the `ViewData.ModelState.Values` collection to see the errors.

```
[Httpost]
public ActionResult Create(User model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     //save and redirect
   }
   else
   {
     foreach (var modelStateValue in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
     {
       foreach (var error in modelStateValue.Errors)
       {               
            var errorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
            var exception = error.Exception;
           // You may log the errors if you want
       }
     }
   }         
   return View(model);
 }
}
```

Comment: I called the View without model arguments and the non-tricky errors showed just fine, whats the pourpuse of calling a view with a model. And how do you log all the errors, i've tried System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("error: " + errorMessage + " ex: " + ex); but it doesn't work.

Comment: Strongly typed approach  always make your code more clean. dynamic stuff like ViewBag makes your code ugly. . you may consider using a logging framework like log4net or Nlog

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // validation error.. display model with error messages

                    return PartialView("partialview", model);
                }
                try
                {
                    //success
                    return Json(new { success = true });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // show error in ValidationSummary

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                    return PartialView("partialview", model);
                }
```